# Find out if Delphi ClassType inherits from other ClassType?

Tags: delphi, inheritance

In Delphi, given the following:

```
TFruit = class;
TFruitClass = class of TFruit;

TApple = class(TFruit);

TRedApple = class(TApple);
```

If I have a `TFruitClass` variable, how can I find out if it inherits from `TApple`? E.g. say I have

```
var
  FruitClass: TFruitClass;
...
FruitClass := TRedApple;
```

How can I verify that FruitClass does indeed inherit from `TApple` in this case? Using `FruitClass is TApple` only works for class instances.

Comment: why? `Assert(FruitClass.InheritsFrom(TApple))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use InheritsFrom:

```
if TApple.InheritsFrom(TFruit) then
  ...
```

You can also use

```
var
  Fr: TFruitClass;
  X: TObject;
begin
  if X.InheritsFrom(TFruit) then
    Fr := TFruitClass(X.ClassType);
end;
```

Comment: It should be noted that runtime type checking is often an indictation that one or more [principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) of object oriented programming are being overlooked (usually a combination of the Liskov substitution principle and the open/closed principle). David should consider a design that doesn't require the caller knowing which descendant of `TFruit` it is calling.

Comment: @codeelegance: though I agree wholeheartedly with you, there are always design trade-offs. And sometimes you just need a method to take any TObject, to fit "interface" or to allow for var parameters and still want to be certain that the instance passed in is of the correct type. In those cases though I usually put the InheritsFrom in an Assert...

Comment: @PatrickvL: I guess it depends on how you read the question. The solution I gave (InheritsFrom) can of course also be used to test whether a variable of TFruitClass type holds a reference to a specific subtype of a TFruit, like the example you gave in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you pass the FruitClass variable along to some method, in which case your should read :

```
  if FruitClass.InheritsFrom(TApple) then
```

Note that you don't even need to test for nil, as InheritsFrom is a class function, and thus does not need the Self variable to be assigned.